# Using Max Function in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the the highest price model for each maker. My output should list the maker, the model and the price.

Here is my schema:

```
   Computer Database schemas:

Product( maker, model, type)
Desktop( model, speed, ram, hd, price)
Laptop( model, speed, ram, hd, screen,      price)
Printer( model, color, type, price)

Products
Maker   Model   Type
A   1001    desktop
A   1002    desktop
A   1003    desktop
B   1004    desktop
B   1006    desktop
B   3002    printer
B   3004    printer
C   1005    desktop
C   1007    desktop
D   1008    desktop
D   1009    desktop
D   1010    desktop
D   2001    laptop
D   2002    laptop
D   2003    laptop
D   3001    printer
D   3003    printer
E   2004    laptop
E   2008    laptop
F   2005    laptop
G   2006    laptop
G   2007    laptop
H   3005    printer
I   3006    printer




Desktop
Model   Speed   Ram HD  Price
1001    2.5 256 80  595
1002    2.0 256 80  399
1003    3.1 512 120 899
1004    3.1 1024    120 999
1005    3.1 256 100 999
1006    4.5 512 180 1099
1007    4.5 512 200 1399
1008    4.0 512 100 1199
1009    4.5 512 120 1299
1010    3.0 256 60  495

Laptop
Model   Speed   Ram HD  Screen  price
2001    1.8 256 30  12  799
2002    2.2 128 20  14  1499
2003    2.2 512 40  14  1699
2004    2.5 256 40  12  1499
2005    2.5 512 60  15  1799
2006    2.3 256 40  15  999
2007    3.0 1024    80  17  1899
2008    2.3 256 30  14  1599

Printer
Model   Color   Type    price
3001    True    InkJet  175
3002    True    InkJet  150
3003    False   Laser   295
3004    False   Laser   325
3005    False   inkjet  80
3006    False   Laser   259
```

This is what I have tried so far, but nothing has really been returning one model per maker that is the highest price. If anyone could help, it'd be really appreciated.

```
SELECT Product.Maker, Laptop.price, Laptop.Model, Desktop.model, Desktop.price

FROM `Laptop`

RIGHT JOIN Product ON Laptop.model = Product.model

LEFT JOIN Desktop ON Product.model = Desktop.Model;
```

Comment: you need to use group by

Comment: And you should normalize your data, so that all of your products are stored in one table, rather have a different table for each type of product.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Lucas Krupinski I tried doing that but now I just get a bunch of syntax errors. Any more advice?